# How to extend one class to two libraries?

Tags: java, android, extends

I want to extend two libraries in one class.

```
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.Fragment;

 public class DisplayAll extends ListActivity extends Fragment{}
```

But java will not support in two extends..How can i do that so that i can extend `ListActivity` and `Fragment` in my `DisplayAll` class .. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Java does not support for Multiple Inheritance. So you cannot extend two classes at the same time. It is better if you extend a ListFragment. See here why Java does not support multiple inheritance. http://javapapers.com/core-java/why-multiple-inheritance-is-not-supported-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Java does not support multiple inheritance.

You can implement multiple interfaces, but not extend multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Java does not support multi level inheritance. You can work around that like below:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.Fragment;

class ListActivityWithFragment extends Fragment{}

public class DisplayAll extends ListActivityWithFragment {}
```

Comment: ListActivityWithFragment does not recognize.. my class here is DisplayAll

Comment: I have updated my answer. Only one public class can be declared in a file. Try the above

Comment: No sir.. ListActivityWithFragment is the error it not recognise

Comment: Can you share the complete source? Maybe as a gist

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Extends class not supported in JAVA.

You can create two different abstract class and use it like as below.

**Your Main Class :**

```
public class DisplayAll extends YourClass1
{

}
```

**Your abstract Class1 :**

```
public abstract class YourClass1 extends YourClass2
{
}
```

**Your abstract Class2 :**

```
public abstract class YourClass2 extends Fragment
{
}
```

Note : You can't extend `Activity` and `Fragment` for single class.

Comment: Sir.. i got only 1 class the DisplayAll.. the Fragment and ListActivity are those i import from libraries

Answer (score 0):

**Java** does not support for **Multiple Inheritance** then **you can't do it** in any way.

If you would like to work with a `ListActivity` and a `Fragment` you should check the [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) or the support-v4 [version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html) and the best way is to use:

```
public class DisplayAll extends ListFragment{

}
```

However currently I suggest you c**hecking the last guidelines and support libraries in Android**.
A good way to work is to use an [`AppCompatActivty`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) and a simple [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) to display a list.

Answer (score 0):

Best shot is nesting the classes i.e. declare the class extending Fragment inside the class extending the class extending ListActivity. This way, inside the nested class extending Fragment you will be able to use everything you create in the class extending ListActivity

**Example:**

```
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.app.Fragment;

 public class DisplayAll extends ListActivity {
   //ListActivity related stuff here
   public class DisplayAllFragment extends Fragment {
       //Fragment related stuff here
       //You can also access the containing class extending ListActivity's stuff here
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.